# Ethiopian calendar in Android

Tags: java, android, datetime, calendar

I am developing an Android app for an Ethiopian company and have to deal with dates.

The calendar used in Ethiopia is similar to the Gregorian one but has two main differences: it's set approx. 7 years earlier and has 13 months.
At the time I post this question the date is 13-09-2021 in the Gregorian calendar and 03-01-2014 in the Ethiopian one.

My questions are:

- does Android support the Ethiopian calendar and is it customary for people in Ethiopia to have their devices use it?
- if so, do I have to get the default formatter (that uses the default calendar: `Calendar.getInstance()`) in order to format the date properly?
- instead, if the device uses the Gregorian calendar how does Java support the translation to the Ethiopian date?

What would you suggest in order to simulate the full scenario, with the device set with the proper current Ethiopian date (as if coming from the network provider) and locale?

Comment: What an interesting question. I can't help but only to tell you when I was doing development a few years ago for Japan I had a heck of a time convincing my test phones that I really wanted to be in Japanese locale. I seem to recall my google ID was somehow tied to my actual home region (US) and it was hindering my testing.

Comment: From some quick Googling, the Ethiopian Calendar is based on the Coptic Calendar, for which I have found docs here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/util/CopticCalendar. Does that help at all?

Comment: I also needed to convert date from ethiopian calendar to gregorian calendar and vice versa for a client project. I copied the conversion from this [EthiopianCalendar](https://github.com/baakal/EthiopianCalendar/blob/master/EthiopianCalendar/Conversion/EthiopianDateConverter.cs) github project. It is written in C# but should be easy to convert to java.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like there's no *Ethiopian* or *Coptic* [`Chronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/Chronology.html) in `java.time` (so far).

Comment: I think this is a cool topic, and I hope you get answers, but you may also want to focus your post down to a single question.

Comment: Besides todays date in ethiopian is 03.01.2014 and not 03.09.2014. I have celebrated the new year 3 days ago :-)

Comment: Maybe you can import the ThreeTen Backport and use its [`CopticChronology`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/chrono/CopticChronology.html)...

Comment: Thank you for all your answers so far! @Eritrean : your nick says it all! Thx for the correction, I was relying on this website https://time.ertale.com/ and Google Translate LOL! Maybe you can tell me if people in Eritrea (and/or Ethiopia) actually use the Ethiopian calendar on their phones or if it's only for public administration and celebrations. I see that you live in Europe so it's even more interesting to know from your point of view. Happy new year! :)

Comment: You may know this, but I'm going to put it here anyway-  I highly suggest you just keep the dates internally as UTC time, and then convert when you display them.  This will keep your app more easily debuggable, and more compatible with third party apps it may need to work with.  Keep the idea of display separate from storage.

Comment: If your app is online maybe you can ask for an API from sites like https://www.ethiopiancalendar.net/ they have calendar app so maybe they use API.

Comment: @qwlice Even today, Ethiopians in Ethiopia use the Ethiopian calendar. In official documents, newspapers, television etc. only the Ethiopian calendar is used. In business, especially in tech, the working language is English and most Ethiopians know the Gregorian calendar and use it professionally on a daily basis. Eritrea, on the other hand, has adapted the Gregorian calendar since independence. in Eritrea, the Ethiopian calendar is only used by older people and in the church. For me and others in europe, it is just used as a reason to celebrate christmas and new year twice.

Comment: unless date and time play an important role in your app, the ability to convert from one to the other is in my opinion a nice-to-have feature rather than a must-have. Please note that the ethiopians also have a different approach to the time of day. the day does not start at midnight but at sunrise in the morning. When the western world has breakfast at 7am it is only the first hour of the Ethiopian day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### About the calendrical background:

The [Ethiopian calendar](https://www.nahmiasreport.com/news/2011/06/15/ethiopian-calendar) is rather a local calendar with some popularity in Ethiopia itself. And yes, there is even a special time keeping mode in this country starting the day at 6 am. However, I am not sure if the calendar is also wide-spread on mobile phones due to lack of sufficient support in the common operating systems like Android, IOS or Windows. Outside of Ethiopia, it is probably only relevant for religous minded Ethiopian people in the diaspora.

### Support on Android:

You can find some support presented by the class [EthiopicCalendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/util/EthiopicCalendar) delivered by IBM. I strongly assume that Amharic numbers are supported (but am not completely sure). I am less confident about the support for 6 am as start of the day and counting as zero (relevant if you ask for the current date). IBM says (similar but not identical to the standard usage of `Calendar.getInstance()`):

> EthiopicCalendar usually should be instantiated using
> Calendar.getInstance(ULocale) passing in a ULocale with the tag
> "@calendar=ethiopic".

The API of IBM offers a translation to the gregorian calendar and vice versa via the counted milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z. For formatting or parsing, use the dedicated [formatter engine of IBM](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/DateFormat). Attention, it is not the standard formatting engine of Android. Of course, you have still to worry with strange features like counting the first month as number zero (instead of one).

### Alternative library Time4A:

My library Time4A is also written for Android and is a sister project of the main lib Time4J. Both libs contain the classes [EthiopianCalendar](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/EthiopianCalendar.html) and [EthiopianTime](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/EthiopianTime.html). You will find some code examples in the javadoc. Support for non-decimal [Amharic numbers](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/format/NumberSystem.html#ETHIOPIC) exists, too. These classes require a special formatting engine, too, called [ChronoFormatter](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/format/expert/ChronoFormatter.html). Like in case of IBM, Ethiopian month names like `Meskerem` (even in Amharic or other languages) are well supported.

A transformation to the gregorian calendar (and vice versa) can be obtained by the expression `ethiopianDate.transform(PlainDate.axis())` where the parameter denotes the target calendar (here, `PlainDate` is the gregorian type).

Answer (score 10):

While I know nothing about these calendaring systems, perhaps…

## *ThreeTen-Extra*

Add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project to access the [`EthiopicChronology`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/chrono/EthiopicChronology.html) class that plugs into the *java.time* framework bundled with Android.

> This chronology defines the rules of the Ethiopic calendar system. This calendar system is primarily used in Ethiopia. Dates are aligned such that 0001-01-01 (Ethiopic) is 0284-08-29 (ISO).

You can also find a [`CopticChronology`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/chrono/CopticChronology.html) class there too.

Comment: That's cool! I am expecting Ole or Meno too to provide a solution using Time4J library.

Comment: The documented transformation from Ethiopian year 1 to gregorian year 284 is not correct. Given the era Amete-Mihret, there are only about seven years difference. Exact: `(English - "Year of Grace") is used for current years >= 1 and starts at AD-8-08-29 (Julian calendar)`